conditionalPanel not working in nested modules
Here is a working example for a conditionalPanel inside a modal dialog in a 1st level module:
library(shiny)
library(bslib)



# Child module server function
childModule <- function(id, run) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns
    
    rv <- reactiveValues(
      show = FALSE
    )
    
    output$show <- reactive(input$number > 5)
    outputOptions(output, "show", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
    
    observeEvent(run(), {
      showModal(modalDialog(
        numericInput(ns("number"), "For Numbers >5 the conditionalPanel should show.", value = 5, min = 0, max = 100),
        
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = "output.show == true",
          ns = NS(id),
          
          "Show Me",
          
          
        ),
      ))
    })
    
  })
}


# UI
ui <- page(
  actionButton("run", "click me")
)

# Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  childModule("child1", reactive(input$run))
}

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui, server)

If you click the button and enter a number > 5 the text is revealed.
However, when I nest the "child"-Module inside a parent module the namespacing of the conditionalPanel is not correct:
library(shiny)
library(bslib)


# Child module server function
childModule <- function(id, run) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns
    
    rv <- reactiveValues(
      show = FALSE
    )
    
    output$show <- reactive(input$number > 5)
    outputOptions(output, "show", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
    
    observeEvent(run(), {
      showModal(modalDialog(
        numericInput(ns("number"), "For Numbers >5 the conditionalPanel should show.", value = 5, min = 0, max = 100),
        
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = "output.show == true",
          ns = NS(id),
          
          "Show Me",
          
          
        ),
      ))
    })
    
  })
}

# Parent module UI function
parentModuleUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  actionButton(ns("run"), "click me")
}

# Parent module server function
parentModule <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    childModule("child1", reactive(input$run))
  })
}

# UI
ui <- page(
  parentModuleUI("parent1")
)

# Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  parentModule("parent1")
}

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui, server)

When inspecting the HTML the problem becomes obvious:
<div class="shiny-panel-conditional" data-display-if="output.show == true" data-ns-prefix="child1-" style="display: none;">Show Me</div>

while it should be data-ns-prefix="parent1-child1-".
Any idea how to fix this?

Inside your module server you have to use the ns from the session, i.e. try with conditionalPanel(condition = "output.show == true", ns = ns, "Show Me") in the childModule server.

@stefan That did the trick. Thank you for the hint. Post it as an answer if you want and I will accept the solution.
